# What is the difference between cat < hello.txt and cat hello (the content of hello.txt is just hello)

Tags: command-line

I created a file `echo hello > hello.txt` and then executed `cat < hello.txt` which gives me "hello", I thought using `< hello.txt` would mean that the variable after `cat` would be the content of the file which is `hello`. However, when I execute `cat hello` it gives me an error because "cat" only deals with files. Can anyone help me understand why this is the case?

Comment: Use `cat hello.txt`? `cat hello` looks for a file named `hello` and `cat < hello.txt` forwards the content of `hello.txt` to `cat`'s **`stdin`**.

Comment: My confusion is using `cat < hello.txt` does not give me an error while `cat hello` does. The content of `hello.txt` is just `hello`.

Comment: `cat hello` starts `cat` with `hello` as an **argument**. `cat < hello.txt` is calling `cat` **without arguments** but with `hello.txt` as standard input. It is the basically same as `cat hello.txt | cat` or `cat hello.txt | cat /dev/stdin`.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks!